# How to list values in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I have a JSON data which is sent to getJSON method. JSON data is

```
[{"Name":"P1","Description":"D1","Attribute":"E,S","Value":"EV,SV"}]
```

and getJSON method

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $.getJSON(url, { Name: 'P1' }, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (k, v) {
            alert(v.Attribute + ' : ' + v.Value);
        });
    });
});
```

I would like to get the alert as

```
E : EV
S : SV
```

Comment: only one alert with linebraks in it or one aler per attribute?

Comment: I just want to see each pair for test purpose, so single or each alert.

Comment: Why don't you send an array Attribute => Value from the server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code here is assuming you have the pair in order. The idea is split the attribute and value, then select the value with same index to alert.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {        
        $.getJSON(url, { Name: 'P1' }, function (data) {
             $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                 var attrs = v.Attribute.split(",");
                 var values = v.Value.split(",");
                 for(var i = 0; i < attrs.length ; i++)
                 {
                    alert(attrs[i] + " : " + values[i]);
                 }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $.getJSON(url, { Name: 'P1' }, function (data) {

    var aSplit=data[0].Attribute.split(',');
    var vSplit=data[0].Value.split(',');
    alert(aSplit[0] + ' : ' + vSplit[0]);
    alert(aSplit[1] + ' : ' + vSplit[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If data is coming as string, then you need to `eval(data)` to get a javascript object.

Try :

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $.getJSON(url, { Name: 'P1' }, function (data) {
        data = eval('('+data+')');
        $.each(data, function (k, v) {
            alert(v.Attribute + ' : ' + v.Value);
        });
    });
});
```